# Printing plots through a function

Tags: r, list, ggplot2

I have a list of lists,

```
item1 <- list(1:5)
item2 <- list(5:10)
item3 <- list(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl) )) + geom_bar())

list <- list("item1"=item1, "item2"=item2, "item3.plt"=item3)
```

In this case, one of the list items has ".plt" as part of it's name. (which holds a ggplot graph)

I'm writing a function to give this list as a parameter, so that it will print all the items which has the ".plt" part as graph objects.

```
print.plots <- function(x){

e <- list2env(x) #do I need this?

list <- list()
  a <- deparse(substitute(x))
  for(i in 1:length(names(x))){
    if(grepl(".plt", names(x)[i])){
      list[i] <- list(paste0(paste0(a,"$"),names(x)[i]))
      # Print here?
    }

  }
  return(list)
}

print.plots(list)
```

I have put the `return(list)` to see what the output is, and it shows me a list of 3 items, the first 2 are `NULL` and the third one has the name of the plot I need to print.

```
[[1]]
NULL
[[2]]
NULL
[[3]]
"list$item3.plt"
```

My `if` condition doesn't seem to not include the list items without ".plt" in their names, and the plot itself is not getting printed (even when I remove the `return` statement). Could anyone help?

Comment: Why create a function? by just calling on your list in the console `list` you should be able to see the plots. or simply use `print(list)` this should plot the plots within your list. Just curious. Why is your list a nested list? Why not just a simple list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something as simple as

```
list[grepl("\\.plt", names(list))]
```

Should give you a result very close to what I think you want form your `print.plots` function.

As for writing a function, a few suggestions.

1. Avoid using the word `list` as an object.  In the example that follows I will us `mylist` instead.
2. Use an underscore, not a dot, for `print_plots`.  The `print.plots` could cause some issues with S3 classes.

In the following example, we look for any item that has the `.plt` as the end of the item and and then returns the name and the prints the plot.

```
library(ggplot2)

item1 <- list(1:5)
item2 <- list(5:10)
item3 <- list(ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=as.factor(cyl) )) + geom_bar())

mylist <- list("item1"=item1, "item2"=item2, "item3.plt"=item3)

print_plots <- function(x) { 
  plts <- grepl("\\.plt", names(x))

  if (any(plts)) {
    message(sprintf("Plots in %s are:", deparse(substitute(x)))) 
    lapply(which(plts), function(i) {y <- unlist(x[i], recursive = FALSE); print(y)}) 
  } else {
    message(sprintf("There are no plots in %s.", deparse(substitute(x)))) 
  }
  invisible(NULL)
}

print_plots(mylist)
# Plots in mylist are:
# $item3.plt
```